# How does one properly install and run the google play store app on a xiaomi redmi 7 pro that was bought in China?

Tags: google-play-store, xiaomi, google-play-services

My cousin has a Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro, Android version 10, MIUI version "MIUI 12.5.1Stable 12.5.1.0(QFHCNXM)" (409dpi) that he bought 'to be delivered from China'.

He recently accidentally deleted the google play store app. When we started trying to fix the problem we first tried making a backup and resetting the device to factory settings, but I misunderstood part of the backup process and skipped a step (i.e actually transferring the backup files to my PC).

The phone was essentially reset without existing backup. Afterwards my cousin tried (without me) to blindly follow Youtube videos that claimed to demonstrate how to install the play store app. I am unable to understand most of those videos since they appear made for audiences that speak asian languages. Afterwards the phone did have the app (as far as I have been able to follow it was downloaded as APK), but it always crashed into the background directly after opening it. Since installing Google Play services (also as APK, 480dpi/ARM64/android10+), the store does no longer crash but also does not react to clicking "sign in" or in any other way.

Sadly I am very much less than a novice when it comes to handheld devices and anything involving them. I do not know how to proceed, but I do have access to my own phone (Huawei P30 lite, model MAR-LX1A, android version 10, EMUI version 10.0.0, decidedly NOT bought in China) with its own Google play store, in case I need a second device for fixing this problem. It may also be simply necessary to tell the device "no we are not in China right now, actually running a google app is allowed you know?" - which should be a software problem, which is about all I know about that.

Comment: So root permissions were used to delete Play store App? Because normally you can't delete, just disable it and after a factory reset everything is back to normal.

Comment: you need to find global version of ROM/firmware https://mifirm.net/model/violet.ttt

Comment: No, he did not have to use root permission to delete the app. When he first bought it he had to apply for permission in the xiaomi store and had the google play store unlocked 2 weeks later.But recently (start of the year or so), China put pressure on Xiaomi to stop supporting/distributing Google apps, including play store and play services.

For a short time some solutions were apparently popular, including an app in the xiaomi store that would install the play store and delete itself - but we seem to have missed the time those solutions were applicable.

Flashing ROM = last resort.